# Having issues with void function

Tags: c++

I'm trying to the program to display the bonus, but the programs renders an answer to 0.  I am extremely new to c++ so any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

//function prototypes
void enterItems(double, double);
void calcAndDisplayBonus(double &salesAmt, double &rate);

int main()
{   
    //declare variables
    double sales     =  0.0;
    double bonusRate =  0.0;

   //enter input values
   enterItems(sales, bonusRate);

   //calculate and display bonus
   cout << fixed << setprecision(2);
   calcAndDisplayBonus(sales, bonusRate);

   system("pause");
   return 0;
}   //end of main function

//*****function definitions*****
void enterItems(double salesAmt, double rate)
{
    cout << "Enter sales: ";
    cin >> salesAmt;
    cout << "Enter bonus rate (in decimal form): ";
    cin >> rate;
} //end of enterItems function

void calcAndDisplayBonus(double &salesAmt, double &rate)
{
    cout << "Bonus: $" << salesAmt * rate << endl;
} //end of calcAndDisplayBonus function
```

Comment: Please make your title useful.

Comment: Use printf if you want formatted text

Comment: @stackptr in C you might do that, in C++ you use stream manipulators like `setprecision()`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts printf is easier for formatted text. Besides, it's faster.

Comment: @stackptr: Debate on whether it's worthwhile to drop back to C functions for specific performant use cases is valuable to have, but not in comments on a question from a novice C++ developer who should not be faced with statements like "use printf" posited as facts without any qualification whatsoever. We have quite enough C++ developers blindly writing in C idioms already, thank you very much.

Comment: @stackptr, easier!? Please name all format specifier that printf supports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `enterItems`, you are passing parameters by copy. This means that your changes won't affect the variables available in the scope of the caller.

To solve it, you can either pass a couple of references or pointers, as well as rely on a pair returned from the function as a result, and so on.

As an example, by writing:

```
void enterItems(double &salesAmt, double &rate)
```

You'll actually solve the problem above mentioned.
Another valid prototype is:

```
void enterItems(double *salesAmt, double *rate)
```

Even though this one asks for a small set of changes all around your code (the example, of course).

There is a plenty of possible solutions, hoping these ones will give you an idea of what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your function

```
void enterItems(double salesAmt, double rate)
```

is taking two double-parameters **by value**, this means, your changes you do inside the function will not be visible from the outside. You could take the doubles by reference:

```
void enterItems(double &salesAmt, double &rate)
```

but i'd prefer to return the values, but since you can only return a single value you'd need two functions:

```
double enterSales()
{
    double tmp;
    cout << "Enter sales: ";
    cin >> tmp;
    return tmp;
}

double enterBonus()
{
    double tmp;
    cout << "Enter bonus rate (in decimal form): ";
    cin >> tmp;
    return tmp;
}

//in your main:
double sales     =  enterSales();
double bonusRate =  enterBonus();
```

Comment: Actually you _can_ return multiple values, but I wouldn't do so here. Your approach looks pretty good (modulo missing `const`).

Comment: Well, you're right, you can return a pair or some struct, but i wanted to keep it simple for now.

Comment: The general advice (which I 100% agree with) is that "returning" by mutating your parameters is ill advised.